# What is the type of each variable i.e. Categorical or Continuous?

Tags: classification

I have following attributes in my data-set.
Name, Date of Birth, Annual Income, Tax Paid, Gender.
What is the type of each variable i.e. Categorical or Continuous? and why ?

PS. I believe categorical attributes are the ones having fixed set of Values. Please let me know if I am wrong with this assumption. Also the "Name" attribute is just a label. but what category does it fall in ?

Comment: A simple google search should help you understand these fairly well- read through http://study.com/academy/lesson/continuous-discrete-variables-definition-examples.html or http://www.dummies.com/education/math/statistics/types-of-statistical-data-numerical-categorical-and-ordinal/

Comment: I have read it already. "Name" attribute is categorical or Continuous ?

Answer (score 1):

Name attribute cant be continuous, if you really want to use it then take it as a categorical. It depends on what is your use case.
Gender is categorical. 
Date of Birth/Annual Income/Tax Paid are in general continuous variable. But you may change them in categorical depending on your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Continuous and discrete data are types of numerical variables, in the sense that one can perform mathematical operations on them ( for example things like height, weight, income, etc.). On the other hand categorical data types are such that fall under a certain category but are not of a mathematical nature (i.e. mathematical operations on such vars make little sense). 
In your example, income and tax paid are numbers, they are continuous, but name, gender and DOB would be categorical.

Comment: Why DOB is categorical and not continuous ?

Comment: I would say that DOB is categorical because we pick one day from a set of all days.  However, if time of birth is accounted for, then it becomes continuous, as time is itself continuous.